# Build errors when switching from buildToolsVersion '24.0.2' to anything higher

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools, android-jack-and-jill

Build fails when switching to buildTooolsVersion 24.0.3 or higher with
error messages relating to Default methods and Static methods "not supported in Android API level less than 24"

Works fine in previous versions of Build Tools, up to 24.0.2
I am using Jack, and Google play-services.
However, the complaints are about code in java.util and java.lang For example:

Error:SortedSet.java:36-37: Default method java.util.Spliterator spliterator() not supported in Android API level less than 24.0.2

Error:Stream.java:68-69: Static method java.util.stream.Stream$Builder builder() not supported in Android API level less than 24

minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 24

Comment: Sound's like you're using java 8 features, check your java version(s)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak. Thanks. Yes, I do use some Java 8 features, such as lambdas, but this all works fine with build tools up to and including 24.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I switched my android studio to use the packaged java 8 version.

When I switched to java 8 I had added the jack enabled and version to 8, but this broke everything for a release build.

I then switched this from true to false.

```
jackOptions {
                enabled false
            }
```

I then set this from 8 to 7.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

I am guessing as long as your code and the libraries you include in your project will work for java 7, your code should build for release.

If this doesn't work and you must use those java functions, it would seem that you will need to move you min version up to 24.

Comment: the problem that I can't do this since I am using labs in my code which requires java8